# Is there a way to build a slightly different app layout in react-native?

Tags: react-native, android-productflavors

I need to build an app with little changes on layout like, logo, default colors, etc...

It's possible to acomplish that in react-native?

I think they call that product flavors on android world...

Comment: What exactly are you even asking with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be possible. A quick search turned up this article on git showing this exact functionality was worked on:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/6010

That being said, it looks as though the command is:

```
react-native run-android --flavor=free
```

Hope this helps!